# What brand and model is this thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

Does anyone know what brand and series this thermostat is? I'm looking to find the user's manual. The cover that flips open fell off and it's lost. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: You can probably pull the unit of the back plate to find some data. It may have release tabs, or it may simply pop off. (You'll need to do that eventually to change batteries anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it could be the **CP1719**, or [one of their related thermostats](http://www.comfortstatusa.com/cs_singlestage.asp), from Comfort Stat.

Here's the manual to that thermostat:
http://www.comfortstatusa.com/thermopdfs/cp1719.pdf